# How to recover a value of a field to stock it in a variable ? Django Admin Form

Tags: jquery, python, json, django

In my `Django Admin Form` I have a `field` which looks like that :

[image]

I would like to complete all `others fields` when I press the `button`  above.

[image]

To do that I am using an `API` which give me a `JSON file` :

```
import requests

post_data = {'cdNom': value}
response = requests.post('https://example/json', data=post_data)
resp = response.json()[0]
print(resp)
```

The variable `value` is not define here but I want to recover `CDN_Name` when I press the button to put this value in the variable.

How can I do that ? It's possible with `python` or I have to use a `jQuery` script in this `HTML button` ?

If I can achieve this, that will recover me a specific `JSON file`, and after I just had to put each `key/value` on the good fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Ajax for this.

The script you show above should be a view that is called by the Ajax script. The view should accept the value as a GET parameter, and return a JSON response consisting of the data to populate the other fields.

So, the Ajax code in jQuery would be:

```
$('#my_button_name').getJSON({
  '{% url "populate_fields" %}',
  {value: $('#id_cdn_name').value()},
  function(data) {
    ... populate other fields with contents of data ...
  }
});
```

and the Django code would be:

```
def populate_fields(request):
    post_data = {'cdNom': request.GET('value')}
    response = requests.post('https://example/json', data=post_data)
    return HttpResponse(response.content)
```

and your urls.py:

```
url(r'populate_fields', views.populate_fields, name='populate_fields'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, that helped me a lot!